# Три зависимых параметра. Изменение одного влияет и на другие, чтобы сумма оставалась неизменна

Tags: java, математика

Необходимо сделать систему балансирующую три положительных переменных.

Например, треугольник телосложения из Fallout 4.

[image: Скриншот из редактора fallout 4]

Необходимо получить что-то вроде:

```java
class BalanceTriangle() {

    float a = 0.33;
    float b = 0.33;
    float c = 0.33;

    static float sum = 0.99;

    void AddA(float value) {
        ...
    }
}

AddA(0.2f); => [0.53f, 0.23f, 0.23f]
```

Я пробовал простейший вариант

```java
void AddA() {
    a += value;
    b -= value/2;
    c -= value/2;
}
```

который успешно срабатывает первый раз, но после нескольких манипуляций одна из переменных может стать отрицательной, что недопустимо.

Тогда я попробовал сбрасывать лишнее вычитание на соседнюю переменную:

```java
void AddA() {
    a += value;

    if (b - value > 0) {
        b -= value/2;
    }
    else {
        float rem = (value/2)-b;
        b = 0;
        c -= rem;
    }

    if (c - value > 0) {
        c -= value/2;
    }
    else {
        float rem = (value/2)-b;
        c = 0;
        b -= rem;
    }
}
```

Но в таком случае сумма по неизвестной причине меняется, а при добавлении операций на каждую переменную всё это выглядит отвратительно.

Подскажите решение задачи.

Comment: В каком диапазоне value может быть ?

Comment: @GinTasan [0; 0.99]

Answer (score 7):

Раз у Вас уже есть наглядное представление в виде треугольника - то и используйте точку внутри треугольника и её  [барицентрические координаты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B)

В английской вики есть [формулы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Conversion_between_barycentric_and_Cartesian_coordinates) для расчёта этих координат из декартовых

Answer (score 2):

Нарисуйте по другому картину. Трехмерная система координат. Из центра постройте сферу радиусом 1. Постройте куб со координатами проходящими через (0,0,0) и (1,1,1). Часть сферы которая внутри куба - это и есть поверхность возможных решений. Ну а далее математика из школы. Берете уравнение сферы - одна координата вам известна. То что все координаты положительны - тоже. Неизвестны оставшиеся две координаты. Тут уж есть возможность для творчества - зависит от того как вы захотите распределять изменения между ними. Короче говоря все сведется к решению квадратного уравнения

Answer (score 2):

Сохранить не только сумму *a+b+c*, но и пропорции между величинами *b* и *c* можно так:

[image: Решение]

Индекс "0" соответствует текущим значениям, "1" - новым.

Например, (0.44, 0.33, 0.22) →(0.64, 0.21, 0.14).

Comment: Тот же результат, что и у автора ОП.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, знаний математики не хватило, чтобы реализовать предложенный товарищем MBo вариант, но в итоге всё решилось проще. 
Сначала я реализовал функцию Set, которая присваивает a определенное значение. Это значение вычитается из необходимой суммы всех параметров, полученное число - остаток, который необходимо распределить между b и c. (rem) Для равномерного изменения я получаю отношение b к оригинальной сумме b+c и аналогично отношение c. (ratio1 и ratio2) Затем из ранее полученного остатка я нахожу необходимую часть, применив отношения. В итоге сумма остаётся неизменна, а части меняются пропорционально оригинальным значениям.

```java
static float sum = 0.99;
static float maxVal = 0.97;

void SetA (float value) {
    if (value >= 0 && value <= maxValue) {
        // находим остаток от присваивания, 
        // который должен распределиться между b и c
        float rem = sum - value;
        // находим отношение b к сумме b и c, аналогично для c
        float ratio1 = b/(sum-a);
        float ratio2 = c/(sum-a);
        // получаем новые значения пропорциональные оригинальным
        b = rem * ratio1;
        c = rem * ratio2;   

        a = value;
    }
}
```

Другие операции на основе этой реализовать не сложно:

```java
void AddA (float value) {
    SetA(a+value);      
}
```

Результаты:

```
SetA(0.5f); =>
   Sum: 0.99
   Params:0.5/0.245/0.245

AddB(0.2f); =>
   Sum: 0.99
   Params:0.36577177/0.445/0.17922819

SetC(0.3f); =>
   Sum: 0.99
   Params:0.31128675/0.37871325/0.3
```